# Select Unique Users who played the game at least 2 or more time per week in 30 days. (SQL/BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a data of users playing multiple games for 6 months

I have Table name : **App_Click**
Column Names: -
**user_id**,
**date**( the date user clicked on game),
**app_name**,
**App_click**( Total Number of Clicks by each user)

if the entry exists than the user have clicked on the app(i.e. played)

Question: I'm looking for the unique users who play the game ABC every week at least 2 or more times in 30 days or Quarterly

Looking Solution like: Total users Who played ABC: 100 (  users who have played other games also)
Total users Who have played only ABC: 30 ( only users who plays only ABC)
Total users Who have played ABC and other games: 70 ( users who playes other games with ABC)

Comment: To be able to answer it properly _you might also add information whether you have traditional SQL database or something different_. And also showing us some examples of what you have tried so far (like some SQL selects perhaps) **Edit**: oh I see SQL tag

Comment: its bigquery
thanks for pointing it out it will keep that in mind for future reference.

Comment: giving us example of input data and expected output will improve your chances to get proper answer - see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How do consider the weeks? The exact weeks or any period of 7 days? The player need to have played more than twice per week in all the weeks in the given month or only one week is enough?

Comment: the player have played every week at least 2 or more times  
let assume a single player playes
week1 played 2(clicks),  
week2 5 ,  
week3 6  and so on

Comment: @Sanji thanks for the information but you didnt answer my other question. What do you consider to be a week?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select countif(num_abc > 0) as num_abc_users,
       countif(num_abc > 0 and num_other = 0) as num_abc_only,
       countif(num_abc > 0 and num_other > 0) as num_abc_plus_other 
from (select user_id, countif(app_name = 'ABC') as num_abc, countif(app_name <> 'ABC') then num_other
      from t
      group by user_id
     ) t;
```

The subquery summarizes for each user.  The outer then aggregates those results.

Comment: Sorry to point it out
but you haven't used the condition atleast 2 or more times per week in 30days